# If a house has mezuzahs and one of bedroom's mezuzah isn't kosher is the entire house at risk or just that bedroom?

Tags: mysticism-kabbalah, mezuzah, practical-kabbalah

I read on this website the entire following article which includes major kabbalistic info about mezuzah protection and I was wondering if any major rabbi or kabbalist or anyone with the answer can answer my simple question.

If you have an entire house affixed with mezuzahs on each doorpost and "Room A" has a pasul mezuzah with chipped letters etc, is "Room A" ONLY not protected or is the entire house now  at risk?

This simple question might sound foolish but it means a lot to me, so if you can answer it please do.

Here's the article I read:
http://www.chabad.org/library/article_cdo/aid/310889/jewish/The-Protective-Power-of-Mezuzah.htm

Comment: It should be noted that the greatest protection is attained through performance of God's will; not through chasing after this or that. The most important thing about _mezuzah_ is simply doing the mitzvah. After that, is its importance in reminding us of God and reminding us not to sin. This is the main thing. Some do not even subscribe to the admittedly common belief that the _mezuzah_ has protective qualities.

Comment: The Rambam states that using *mezuzoth* in such a fashion (i.e. as a protective amulet) is forbidden. There is no such power inherent in them - at all. Kol tuv.

Comment: @mevaqesh Indeed, the linked to article unfortunately speciously blurs that distinction in numerous places.

Comment: @Maimonist I know but especially since the practice was and is very widespread I thought that a more gentle approach was appropriate.

Comment: most "stories" ascribe one room missing from an otherwise "protected" house to be a chink in the armor, and not as if the whole house is open.

Comment: related: http://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76047/8775.