# Tzitzit being a protection to the wearer

Tags: sources-mekorot, tzitzis, superstition

What is the source for tzitzit being a protection for the wearer? And is it also a protection when there is no mitzvah being fulfilled while wearing them, for example at night?

Comment: See [this](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Tzitzit#Time_Requirements) page from [Halachipedia](http://halachipedia.com/index.php?title=Main_Page). I don't know how accurate the information is, but they provide some concise endnotes for each fact with references.

Comment: @ezra Thanks i found it in the כף החיים, but didn't see a source in the  ben ish chai they quoted.

Comment: Note that this belief is not universal. Rambam, for example is strongly opposed to such ideas. See [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/64570/8775), and [here](https://judaism.stackexchange.com/a/76047/8775).

Answer (score 2):

I found this in the Kaf Hachayim ([21:15](http://www.hebrewbooks.org/pdfpager.aspx?req=14418&st=&pgnum=86)):

> צריך ליזהר שלא להסיר מעליו ציצית קטן לא ביום ולא בלילה וישכב עמו בלילה ויועיל מאוד לבטל כוחות החיצונים...
>
> There is a need to be careful to not remove from upon himself the Talit Katan, not at day and not at night and he should sleep with it at night and it helps a lot (the Tzitzit help) to nullify the outer powers...

Answer (score 0):

There is a story in the Talmud which is about a student who was careful in observing the mitzvah of tzitzis which protected him from committing a sin of immorality it can be found in Menachos on page 44a. Here is a link to read online in English... https://halakhah.com/pdf/kodoshim/Menachoth.pdf